# Why don't appointment times show on my iCloud Calendar

Tags: icloud, calendar

Maybe I'm confused.  I'm using Mac Leopard, so I have to use the iCloud website in order to post appointments on my calendars.  The appointment times show up on my iPhone and my iPad, but don't show up on my iCloud Calendar.  There is just a solid dot as if it were and "all day" appointment.  I can't seem to find anyone who has asked this question before anywhere on the web.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[image: iCloud View]

It sounds like you may not have your views set to see the items, or that you have the view in MONTH, and the screen is just too small to show them as a 'boxed' houly appointment. 
Try enabling all the calendars, or at least the calendar you use, and then check the list or Day view, and see if they show up.

If this is the wrong Idea, can you submit a screen shot of what you see?